# Comparing PHP DateInterval

Tags: php, date

how can you compare two DateInterval objects?
something like:

```
$d1 = new DateInterval("P1M");
$d2 = new DateInterval("P2M");

if($d2 > $d1)
{
    do something ...
}
```

I could convert the DateIntervals to seconds but is there some kind of better way?

Thank you for your help!

Best regards,

Freddy

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Converting to seconds is the only way so far.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a reasonable approach. Apply the DateIntervals to a DateTimeImmutable and then compare the dates.

```php
$startDate = new \DateTimeImmutable();
$endDate1 = $startDate->add($dateInterval1);
$endDate2 = $startDate->add($dateInterval2);
return $endDate1->getTimestamp() === $endDate2->getTimestamp();
```